# How do you get innerText from a td class, to be bold?

Tags: javascript, html-table, innertext

I have a table which looks like this :

```
<div class="table">
                 <table>

                    <tr>
                        <th>FORce</th>
                        <th>DEXtérité</th>
                        <th>CONstitution</th>
                        <th>INTelligence</th>
                        <th>SAGesse</th>
                        <th>CHArisme</th>
                    </tr>

                     <tr class="chiffres">
                        <td class = "FOR">

                        </td>

                        <td class = "DEX">

                        </td>

                        <td class= "CON">

                        </td>

                        <td class ="INT">

                        </td>

                        <td class="SAG">

                        </td>

                        <td class="CHA">

                        </td>
                     </tr>


                </table>

            </div>
```

And here is my Javascript code :

```
function Recommand(){

if(document.getElementsByClassName("SAG").innerText >= 13)
    {
        document.getElementById("radio7").innerText.style.fontWeight="bold";
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that if SAG.innerText >= x number, the id that I choose, becomes bold?

Also, I'm using and anonymous function to execute my function when my page loads.

```
aPar[4].addEventListener("load", Recommand());
```

My TD class holds a number, and that number will be in direct relation with my radio button, who also has a innerText value my "radio7" ID looks a little something like this :

```
<label><input type="radio" id = "radio7" 
name="radio1"/> Clerc</label>
```

What I want to become bold, is the "Clerc" string from the radio.

Comment: innerText returns a string.... Apply the style to the TD And `aPar[4].addEventListener("load", Recommand());` is wrong. What is `aPar[4]` exactly? Your function calls he method and sets whatever it returns to the event listener. And since you method appears to not return anything, you are assigning undefined to the event listener.

Comment: var oDoc = document;
var aPar = oDoc.querySelectorAll("p");

I used to method to load my function when going into the next part of my website, since I'm not allowed to use multiple HTML pages, I figured this would work..

Comment: `p` elements do not have a load event....

Comment: That is not the problem.. the problem is that, it's showing "style="font-weight: bold;" when I inspect the HTML code.. but it dosen't apply it

Comment: It is a problem. A BUG is your code is the only reason why it is running in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `document.getElementsByClassName()` it returns an array. So you'd have to use it like this:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("SAG")[0].innerText >= 13)
{
    ...
}
```

That means that you'll get the first element that has the class "SAG". If you have more elements with the same you could try to loop through them.

EDIT: The text is inside the label, not the radio button, so you can put the id inside the radio button and then try again. Or you can use JQuery and get the parent of the input element and then apply the style.

What I'm saying is that you'd have to put it something like this:

```
<label id="radio7"><input type="radio" name="radio1"/>Clerc</label>
```

And instead of applying it using the `style.fontWeight` you could just change the text to be bold like this:

```
document.getElementById("radio7").innerText= "<b>" + document.getElementById("radio7").innerText + </b>;
```

This just adds `<b>` and `</b>` before and after the text thus making it bold.

Comment: Apparently putting ID inside the label worked! Thanks alot!